# How to check if e.value is empty since the e.oldValue update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Awhile back google changed how e.value works; adding e.oldValue.

Before this change you could check if e.value was empty by using:

```
if (e.value) {
  //  do stuff
}
```

Since the change when e.value is empty it'll always return {oldValue=XXX}, which fails the above check.

So how do I check for an empty value if can't ever be empty anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
if (typeof e.value !== 'object') {
 //  do stuff
}
```